# Responsive website looks fine when browser resizing but awkward in real ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ipad

I already have this code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

The page looks absolutely fine in desktop browsers when resizing it to smaller screen. Also perfect on responsinator and several other websites. However when loaded on a real iPad it looks very awkward.

Here is how the page should look and it does look on desktop browser: 
[image]

and here is how it looks on real iPad:

[image]

Is there any tool out there which could possibly show what is shown on real iPad on desktop?

Comment: I use **<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">** for seting the viewport and it works fine. For real testing you could use [mobiletest](http://mobiletest.me)

Answer (score 2):

Try this meta tags

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">   
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
```

Hope this help